# Why increasing the voltage of the anode with respect to the cathode has no effect on the photocurrent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, photoelectric-effect

> As light strikes the emitting electrode, electrons are ejected. But not all of the ejected electrons are collected at collecting electrode since they don't all get ejected in the same direction. Increasing the positive potential of the collecting electrode attracts these electrons to it (the collecting electrode has a positive potential, not the emitting electrode), and after a certain amount of potential all the ejected electrons are being collected and a further increase in potential does nothing.

But wouldn't the increase in voltage further increases the kinetic energy of the photoelectrons. Therefore, decreasing the amount of time they take to go through the wire's cross section, hence increasing the current nevertheless?

Comment: link to the quote? For a good link see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod2.html

Comment: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/photoelectric-effect-saturation-current.720506/#:~:text=Increasing%20the%20positive%20potential%20of,increase%20in%20potential%20does%20nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speed of charge is not current, the count per unit time is.

You might be imagining a normal circuit which could have a fixed amount of mobile charge inside.   In that case faster movement of the charges will result in higher current (since the more quickly this group of charges moves, the more times they can complete a circuit).

Here though, the emitting electrode is creating an amount of charge per unit time (based on the intensity of the light).   It doesn't matter how fast or slow the charges go.   *Once the current reaches steady state*, then as long as they all reach the collecting electrode, the current must be equal to the rate of charge production.

If the doors out of an auditorium will allow 100 people to exit every minute, and then the crowd has to go downstairs and exit, it doesn't matter if they have a fast escalator that gets them there in 30 seconds, or if they have to walk down several long hallways and it takes them 5 minutes.   The "current" of people exiting building will also be 100 people per minute.

Comment: So you're saying that the kinetic energy does increase between the electrodes, and the electrons get faster. However, once they are at the anode, they will enter the wire at the same rate، say for  example 2000 electrons per unit time regardless of how much kinetic energy they had upon entering, right?

Comment: Yes.  If you're only measuring current, you don't have information about KE.

Comment: I have one more question. Given what you said, then the current between the cathode and the anode will be more than the current in the circuit. If I got what you said right, then wouldn't this violate KCL?

Comment: What is the current in "the circuit"?   Why would the current due to the photoelectrons be greater?  (This sounds like a separate question rather than a comment on the original.   You might want to make sure you have an explicit diagram if you ask it so that everyone is clear on exactly which parts you're asking about.)

Comment: I am saying that given that between the anode and the cathode, electrons can move faster, therefore, more electrons per unit time, but even though this is the case, electrons enter the anode at the same rate nevertheless, so applying KCL at the anode, the current in wouldn't equal the current out.

Comment: @Jack - 'electrons can move faster' is true, but that just means they're strung farther apart.   It doesn't mean more electrons cross the finish line per unit time.